# ATG promotion to apply for a specific day of week

Tags: java, atg

How to set up ATG promotions through BCC for every Wednesday, 10% discount has to be added for any promotions without a manual amendment?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would require customization beyond my skills to support this. BCC's promotion templates OOTB support only the following date/time-based rules...

- Spend since a specific date
- Active between specific dates
- Active on a specific date
- Active until a specific date
- Active during only specific times of the day

But nothing like a recurring logical or relative date such as an every Wednesday rule or a good for one day every 7 days starting this Wednesday, etc.

The system has no knowledge of WEDNESDAY. The customization would likely need to know the current year, lookup and persist all the dates of all the Wednesdays for that given year, then apply logic to enable the promotion only on those Wednesdays. At a guess.